# Splitting file using prefix

Tags: shell-script

I need to split a file into 5 parts but the tricky part to append the numeric number in the prefix of the filename and not at the end.

```
split -n 5 -d -a 2 "$file" "$file"
```

Name of the file:- file = text

creates the text01 but I want 01text.

Answer (score 4):

With GNU `split`:

```
split -n 5 -d -a 2 --additional-suffix="$file" "$file" ""
```

Answer (score 0):

Using sed

```
$ ls bob*
bob-00  bob-01  bob-02  bob-03

$ ls bob* | sed 's,\(bob-\(.*\)\),mv \1 \2-bob,' | sh -x 
+ mv bob-00 00-bob
+ mv bob-01 01-bob
+ mv bob-02 02-bob
+ mv bob-03 03-bob

$ ls *bob
00-bob  01-bob  02-bob  03-bob
```

I used "bob-" instead of "text" but it is easy to adapt